Zod set validation min / max / length numbers asynchronously
In Zod, we can set the values like this
z.string().max(5);
z.string().min(5);
z.string().length(5);

But in my case the values are (eg: 5) are not pre-defined. They're coming from an API.
How do I build the zod schema with the values are set asynchronously?

You can try something like below,

First, fetch data asynchronously.
Create the Zod schema with the dynamic data

async function createZodSchema() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    
    // fetch length data asynchronously 
    const lengthData = await fetchLengthConstraints();

    // assuming that the lengthData has the below maxLength, minLength and exactLength property. Replace the properties as per your need

 
    const schema = z.string()
      .max(lengthData.maxLength)
      .min(lengthData.minLength)
      .length(lengthData.exactLength);
  
      resolve(schema);
  });
}

let lengthSchema = await createZodSchema();
let result = lengthSchema.safeParse("Your Data");

